# Set of points $x$ in $[0,1]$ supporting a decimal expansion without $2$'s and $3$'s and find $m(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ denote the set of points $x$ in $[0,1]$ supporting a decimal expansion without $2$'s and $3$'s. Show that $E$ is a measurable set, and find $m(E)$

Could you please give me a hint?

I believe, that $x=0.x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}....= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{j}10^{-j}$, with each $x_{j}\in{0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $E_j$ is the set of points in $E$ whose first digit after the decimal point is $j$, then $m(E) = m(E_0) + m(E_1) + m(E_4) + \ldots + m(E_9)$ and $m(E_j) = m(E)/10$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Let $K_n$ but the set of numbers whose first $n$ decimals contain no twos or threes.  There are $10^n$ possible options for the first $n$ digits to be and of those, $8^n$ have no twos or threes.  So $m(K_n) = (\frac 45)^n$.

$E \subset K_n$ for all $n$ so $m(E) \le m(K_n) = (\frac 45)^n$ for all $n$.  So...

Comment: @ fleablood is that $\sum_{x_{j}=0 \\ x_{j} \neq 2,3 \\ j=1,...,n}^{10}  \frac{2}{10^{n}}$??

Comment: Um....no.  It's that $\lim (\frac 45)^n = 0$.

Comment: For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n$ so that $(\frac 45)^n = m(K_n) < \epsilon$.  So $m(E) < \epsilon$ for all positive numbers.  As $m(E) \ge 0$ and $m(E) < \epsilon$ for any positive $m(E) = 0$.

Comment: Actually I cut a bit of a corner in that anything with a 2 and trailing zeros or 3 with trailing nines might not (or might) be in E.  That can easily be fixed by saying redefining K_n not to include those either.  Then m(E) $\le m( K_n) = (8^n + 2n)/10^n$ the limit of which also goes to 0.  ... I'm not sure why I didn't just to a cantor set argument....

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is just like the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) except you are removing $\frac{1}{5}$ of the interval each time. As with the Cantor set, the complement is a dense open subset of $[0, 1]$.